# Having trouble with git-bash alias

Tags: git, git-bash

I have been trying to setup gitbash alias in my config file, but it does not work.
When I type in junit it says command not found, but when I list the alias, it shows the command.

```sh
> junit
  bash: junit: command not found

> git la
  junit=java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
  la=!git config -l| grep alias | cut -c 7-
```

Comment: For better reading experience, please copy paste the text of console output. You may mask any confidential information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `junit` is a `git` alias, not `bash` alias so you have to run it with git:

```
git junit
```

But first you need to fix it: `git config alias.junit '!java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore'` (`!` to run an external program. Without it `git` thinks it's an alias for its internal command.)

If you want to make `junit` a shell alias you should define it in the shell config file. For `bash` it's `~/.bashrc` and the syntax is

```
alias junit='java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore'
```

Don't forget to re-read it using `. ~/.bashrc` after changing the file.

Comment: @Zereges Of course, but [not all shells](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh) have the command `source` and most of them have `.`